# Block DNS Lookup on Curl (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, dns

How I can block the DNS Lookup on Curl?

So, I think have two alternatives, there is:

1. Use HTTP (or another type?) Proxies. But, the DNS Loockup will be made by Proxy or the 'original' server?

Exemple:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '0.0.0.');

2. Set a default DNS for domain. In Windows se have a "ETC/HOSTS" file, but where it is on Centos? How I can set this default in CURL? Because the CURL will continue try find the DNS.

This will work?

Thank everyone. :)

Comment: http has very little to do with dns, other than http uses dns to resolve hostname->ip, like pretty much everything else on the net. if you don't want a dns lookup performed, then don't use hostnames: use IPs only.

Comment: But the direct IP not work on CURL. I try it. :/

Comment: probably because the site you're trying to reach is being name-hosted, which REQUIRES a `Host:` header, e.g. curl to the IP, but force `Host: example.com` in the request headers.

Comment: In CentOS, it's actually at etc/hosts.  as in /etc/hosts ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to force a request to a different server than what DNS specifies then you *can* muck with `/etc/hosts` or `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`, **OR** you can do it purely through cURL by manually setting a host header.

```
$hostname = 'www.mydomain.com';
$ip = '1.2.3.4';
$proto = 'http';
$request = '/foo/bar/index.php';

$url = sprintf('%s://%s%s', $proto, $ip, $request); // http://1.2.3.4/foo/bar/index.php

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Host: '.$hostname]);
curl_exec($ch);
```